Best outdoor exhaust fan to indoor room? Not kitchen
I need to buy an exhaust fan for our cat litter room that goes directly on the wall to the outside. We need filtered/fresh air in this room because it otherwise does not have air movement and it stinks!
How do I do what I need to do? What would something like this be called? And what brands sell something high quality like this that can be at least mildly weather/outdoor proofed? I imagine it might be hard to find something completely enclosed/weather proofed. I’m willing to spend in order to get the proper product right off the bat, but all the suggestions I see are for bathrooms or kitchens and I’m not sure exhaust fans like that would work for this purpose.
Or maybe there’s another option that I can utilize, just looking for help as a new homeowner!

you can mount a bathroom fan on the wall.  what do you feel is inadequate in a bathroom fan?

Unclear; Both kitchen and bathroom fans exhaust air to the outside - only a few (typically 1960's or full on commercial kitchen fans) put the fan itself outside - most the fan is inside and all that's outside is the end of the vent. Other ventilation fan options include Heat or Energy Recovery Ventilators (HRVs/ERVs) which will exhaust and bring in fresh air, again, with the fan (and heat exchanger) part normally located inside the building envelope, not out in the weather

Almost any exhaust fan of the right size will remove stinky air to the outside.  The problem is to have a vent in the wall/door so fresh air can replace the air exhausted.

As is, the question asks for specific product recommendation, which is off topic. It also needs to be more focused. Please edit it to make a single question that is answerable, E.G., "Could a through-the-wall vent fan be used to reduce odors in a room?"

That's somewhat overstating the case, @DrMoishePippik - "What would it be called" is on topic, "What brands..." isn't on topic, but is not a specific product ask.

Unless you live where heating or cooling is not required, probably the best option for exhaust and fresh air would be a Heat Recovery Ventilator or Energy Recovery Ventilator (HRV/ERV) with the choice of which is better for your climate depending on your climate.
There are many options, (more efficient ones normally cost more, but "buying the most expensive one" probably won't pay back in a lot of situations) and almost all of them only have vent grills exposed to the weather - the rest of the unit and the motors, etc. are typically located in the house (sometimes in an attic or basement space, depending on the installation.)
Kitchen and bath exhaust fans would also work for exhaust only if you don't mind sucking fresh air in via leaks and your house is old and leaky enough that it will - those also do not normally have any moving parts out in the weather, and the few that might will be built to take it (but are not common in household fans.) I'd consider many of them too noisy for running all the time, though, and they may also lack the sort of power efficiency you'd like (along with low noise) for something intended to run 24/7/365.
Additional options would be to use a motion sensor to run the fan faster for some minutes when there is motion in the room (needs to be a sensor that responds to a cat) and possibly one of the robotic-auto-scooping cat boxes to reduce the stink at it's source, not knowing what sort of litterbox management you do or don't employ already.
